# split integer from string

Tags: java, arrays, split

I'm importing a text file with multiple lines like this

```
 0     2     23
 1     3     34
 2     4     45
12     5     56
```

I'm using this to read the file and split the values

```
while (txtFile.hasNext()) {

    String str = txtFile.nextLine();
    String[] parts = str.split("\\s+");
```

Based on this regex, the 1st three lines will have parts[1] [2] and [3], when it comes to the 4th line, it becomes parts[0] [1] and [2]

My question is which regex should I use to overcome this problem so it can read part[0] [1] and [2] for all the lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trim the leading whitespace from the input `String`

```
String str = txtFile.nextLine().trim();
```

Comment: Thank you, so simple but couldnt think of trim()